# Unable to reset email or password due to Firebase site not found problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-hosting, reset-password

I recently attempted to implement the ability to reset a user's email and password in my Flutter application. It sent the email successfully but shortly after I clicked on the URL link I was met with a "Site Not Found". Multiple options on why this message was being displayed were listed below but they had to do with Firebase Hosting or using a custom domain which I use neither of them. I viewed multiple Youtube tutorials to see if they ran into similar problems but the link took them to a elegantly formatted website where they were able to reset their email or password. I am not sure why this problem is occurring but it might be due to the fact that I need a custom domain, although none of the Youtubers required it.

Below is the error I'm faced with on the site:

[image: Site not found]

Below is the Flutter code:

Firebase Auth:

```yaml
  firebase_auth: ^0.17.0-dev.2
```

Reset password:

```
  Future<void> resetPassword(String email) async {
    await _authInstance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
  }
```

Reset email:

```
  Future<void> resetEmailAddress(
      String newEmail, String oldEmail, String password) async {
    var authResult = await _authInstance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: oldEmail, password: password);
    await authResult.user.updateEmail(newEmail);
    await _instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(authResult.user.uid)
        .update({'email': newEmail});
  }
```

Lastly I'm sorry for the lack of error checking and thank you for you time!

Comment: the problem is not about the flutter code, can you check the authentication page on firebase console https://ibb.co/GscFQ2Q

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong in the Firebase console that I can see. [Firebase console](https://imgur.com/a/sfsaksh)

Comment: your website seems offline you can check it here https://expense-application-online.firebaseapp.com/ probably it will be fixed to activate the hosting

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/

Comment: I activated hosting but this did not solve the problem. [Hosting](https://imgur.com/a/EHbr0sk). Are you suggesting I need to create a basic website to fulfill this purpose? Because, I have seen no other tutorial have to use hosting or creating a basic website for a Flutter mobile app which confuses me on why it is not working automatically.